# How to make a number that is equal to all numbers

Tags: javascript, numbers, html5-canvas

I am making a platformer game that has multiple levels. I have code written so that a certain platform object only draws and has collision detection if its level property is equal to the current level. This is good for most of the platforms that only appear on one level, but I am not sure how to have platforms that appear on all levels (such as borders). Is there a number that I can put into the platform dictionary that will equal all integers so that it will appear on every level?

I have tried putting the level property equal to true, but in javaScript true is equal to one, but not any other number.

```
//The dictionary for a platform
var leftBorder = {
    x:0,
    y:0,
    width:5,
    height:canvas.height,
    level: ??? //the level property that needs to equal any posative integer
};


if(leftBorder.level == currentLevel){
    drawPlatform(leftBorder);
}
```

Comment: Why not just add a second check to your if statement e.g. `if (... || leftBorder.level == some_magic_number)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could add a second property that identifies the borders to be drawn on all levels, and also check that. i.e. sometine like

```js
//The dictionary for a platform
var leftBorder = {
    x:0,
    y:0,
    width:5,
    height:canvas.height,
    level: ???, //the level property that needs to equal any posative integer
    drawOnAllLevels: true
};


// Checks the levels are equal, if not checks if it should draw on all levels anyway
if(leftBorder.level == currentLevel || leftBorder.drawOnAllLevels){
    drawPlatform(leftBorder);
}
```

Comment: This is the way to go!